# Unable to run Vmware workstation 11 - failed to build vmnet

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and vmware workstation 11.
When I tried to open vmware it told me that serval modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernal (my kernal version is 3.13.0-51-generic ) and when I complete the preocess it gave the error: `Unable to start services`.
Here is the log:

```
 2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=7438 version=11.0.0 build=build-2305329 option=Release
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Host is Linux 3.13.0-51-generic Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-05T09:09:07.484+01:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.515+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-7438.log
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-51-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.521+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.525+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.525+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.613+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-05T09:09:07.613+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 17459 symbol versions
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.628+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.630+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.630+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.631+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.631+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.632+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.632+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.634+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.634+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.635+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.644+01:00| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2015-05-05T09:09:07.644+01:00| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-51-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.654+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.659+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.659+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.749+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-05T09:09:07.749+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.765+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 17459 symbol versions
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.766+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.770+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.770+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.771+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Unable to find a GCC compiler in the system path.  Attempting to use a compiler at location "/usr/bin/gcc-4.8".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.773+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "4.8".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.773+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.773+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc-4.8".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.775+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "4.8".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.775+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.778+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.783+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.783+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.784+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.784+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.784+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.784+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.784+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.788+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.788+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.788+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-51-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.789+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:07.793+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.793+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:07.879+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-05T09:09:07.879+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.895+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 17459 symbol versions
2015-05-05T09:09:07.895+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.896+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:07.896+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-05T09:09:07.898+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:08.044+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2015-05-05T09:09:08.044+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2015-05-05T09:09:08.050+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2015-05-05T09:09:08.050+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-0WioTK/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-05T09:09:08.132+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2015-05-05T09:09:08.134+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-05-05T09:09:08.134+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2015-05-05T09:09:08.137+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-05-05T09:09:08.137+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-0WioTK/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-05T09:09:08.287+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.679+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.679+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.679+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:21.679+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.679+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:21.683+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.683+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.13.0-51-generic to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.684+01:00| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 for preprocess check
2015-05-05T09:09:21.688+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.13.0-51-generic".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.688+01:00| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.13.0-51-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-05T09:09:21.777+01:00| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-05T09:09:21.777+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.794+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Read 17459 symbol versions
2015-05-05T09:09:21.794+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.796+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.796+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.798+01:00| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.988+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmmon to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/misc/vmmon.ko".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.988+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmmon source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar".
2015-05-05T09:09:21.994+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmmon source.
2015-05-05T09:09:21.994+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-bMIPv4/vmmon-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-05T09:09:22.080+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2015-05-05T09:09:22.081+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-05-05T09:09:22.081+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2015-05-05T09:09:22.086+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-05-05T09:09:22.086+01:00| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-bMIPv4/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.8 IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-05T09:09:22.239+01:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/618503/edit) your question and add your kernel version:  `uname -r`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

VMware Workstation 11.1.0 and Player (Pro) 7.1.0 support kernels up to 3.18. You can apply a patch:

```
curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r *-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

<sub>[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels_and_up)</sub>

Comment: I had an error while executing the last statement
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Erreur 2
make: quittant le répertoire « /tmp/modconfig-DaBTuA/vmnet-only »
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details. »

Comment: I can not read French. Use `LANG=C`

Comment: make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[2]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-ct7Kkf/vmnet-only/driver.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-ct7Kkf/vmnet-only/driver.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-ct7Kkf/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-51-generic'
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-ct7Kkf/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

Comment: Run `gcc --version` or `which gcc`

Comment: Works for me perfectly! Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel - 3.19.0-31-generic. I installed - VMware-Workstation-Full-11.0.0-2305329.x86_64

Comment: make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-rucvBU/vmnet-only/hub.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-rucvBU/vmnet-only] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.18.3-031803-generic'
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/tmp/modconfig-rucvBU/vmnet-only'
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.

Comment: i am having the above errors while running last command......i am having Ubuntu 14.04 and 32 bit machine

Comment: @VasuDevGarg comments are for clarifications. Ask a new question.

Comment: @A.B. ok thanks for telling.......... i have asked a new question at  http://askubuntu.com/questions/715788/virtual-network-device-error-in-vmware