# Install VMWare under 15.04

Tags: vmware

I am trying to install VMWare under Ubuntu 15.04, which was successful but when I start it I get the following dialog:

[image]

When then clicking install I get

[image]

I checked the log file which tells me

```
2015-06-02T12:55:08.669+01:00| vthread-3| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Then I tried to use the patch from 
[Unable to run Vmware workstation 11 - failed to build vmnet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618503/unable-to-run-vmware-workstation-11-failed-to-build-vmnet)

but when executing the last line `vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` gives me the error:

```
    Stopping VMware services:
       VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
       VM communication interface socket family                            done
       Virtual machine communication interface                             done
       Virtual machine monitor                                             done
       Blocking file system                                                done
    make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only'
    Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
    /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/hashFunc.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/task.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1342:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
     LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
     ^
      LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
      Building modules, stage 2.
      MODPOST 1 modules
      CC      /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
      LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
    /usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
    make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only'
    make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only'
    cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
    make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmmon-only'
    make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only'
    Using 2.6.x kernel build system.
    /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
      MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/driver.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/hub.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/userif.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/bridge.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/procfs.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/smac.o
    In file included from include/linux/pci.h:34:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
    include/linux/pci_ids.h:2251:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
     #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
     ^
    In file included from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
     ^
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c: In function ‘VNetNetIf_Create’:
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:64: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
        dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
                                                            ^
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        dev = alloc_netdev(sizeof *netIf, deviceName, VNetNetIfSetup);
          ^
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:152:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
      CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c: At top level:
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.c:85:1: warning: ‘VNetNetIfSetup’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     VNetNetIfSetup(struct net_device *dev)  // IN:
     ^
    scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/netif.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    In file included from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
    /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
     #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD
     ^
    In file included from include/linux/pci.h:34:0,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
             from /tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only/bridge.c:51:
    include/linux/pci_ids.h:2251:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad
     ^
    Makefile:1394: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only' failed
    make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-18-generic'
    Makefile:130: recipe for target 'vmnet.ko' failed
    make: *** [vmnet.ko] Error 2
    make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-SZC8B2/vmnet-only'
    Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: That did not work for my case I updated a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haved solved this issue, since it turns out to be connected to kernel versions 3.19+.
Here is the link to the patch
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels